# Disable tint color on iOS 8 More TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating the UITabBarItem for my ViewControllers contained in the TabBarController with the new recommended method

```
        UIImage * normal = [UIImage imageNamed:viewIconKey];
        normal = [normal imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        UIImage * selected = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@On",viewIconKey]];
        selected = [selected imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

        self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:self.title
                                                        image:normal
                                                selectedImage:selected];
```

of creating my images with `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` to keep the blue tint from applying.

This works fine on the normal Tab Bar Items, but when I select the "More" tab (I have 9 items in the viewControllers collection), then the icon displayed next to each item is tinted in the "blue" color.

On iOS 7 this does not happen, the icons retain their original color.

Any ideas? New API in iOS 8 for this? The More Tab Controller has always been a PITA.

Answer (score 0):

UITabBarController exposes the MoreTab as a navigation controller called `moreNavigationController`. You can customize it as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5871528/442328).

Hope  this helps

Comment: I am already using this method to customize the view, but nothing in there controls the way the UIMoreListController displays the icons